# loop through data faster (maintain order of calculated values in new vector)

Tags: r

Is there a faster way to do the following calculations without using two loops while maintaining the order of the new calculated vector?

```
# apply this function to a data.frame to create a new vector 

std = function(m)
{
    ret = (m - mean(m))/sd(m)
 }
```

#
 create data frame

```
x  = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2012-01-01"), to  = as.Date("2014-01-01"), by = "months") - 1
y  =  c("A","B","C","D","E")
z  = rnorm(500)

x1  = sample(x = x, size = 500, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
y1  = sample(x = y, size = 500, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
z1  = sample(x = z, size = 500, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)

df = cbind.data.frame(x1,y1,z1)



vec = rep(NA, nrow(df))
```

#
run calculations

```
# first loop through the dates in df[,"x1"]
# apply the function std  to each set of values in df[,"y1"] for each date 

for(i in 1:length(x))   
{

idx = df[,"x1"] == x[i]

for(j in 1:length(y))
{
    idx2           =df[idx,"y1"] == y[j]
    vec[idx][idx2] = std(df[idx,"z1"][idx2])

} #end j loop


} # end i loop
```

## I need to maintain the order of the vec with the data.frame df

```
cbind(df,vec)
```

Comment: The variable `out` is not defined so the code cannot be run. Can you describe in words what you expect this code to do?

Comment: Added some additional code and comments

Answer (score 2):

This is really what the `ave` function is for. You can just do

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(x1,y1,z1)
vec <- with(df, ave(z1,x1,y1,FUN=std))
```

for more information, read the `?ave` help page